# Routes not found - API on planethoster

Tags: api, express, routes, server

I currently put an api on a planetHoster server and it does not work while locally everything works. I share the code below. The error is that my route is not found while the path is correct.

I simplified my code as much as possible with the minimum of routes and an internal base which is initially on mongoose.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions :)

```
Server.js


const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 

const idccRoutes = require('./routes/idcc');

 

 

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

 

app.use((req, res, next)=>{
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS'){
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
        return res.status(200).json({});
    }
    next();
});
 

 

app.use('/idcc', idccRoutes);

 

app.use((req, res, next)=>{
    const error = new Error('not found !');
    error.status = 404;
    next(error);
})

 

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(error.status || 500);
    res.json({
        error: {
            message: error.message
        }
    });
});

 

module.exports = app;
```

```
idcc.js (route)

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const IDCC =  require('./table/idcc.json');


router.get('/list', (req, res, next)=>{
    IDCC.find().exec().then(docs => {
        console.log(docs);
        res.status(200).json(docs);
    })
});

 

module.exports = router;
```

```
idcc.json (db)

{
    "IDCC" : [
        {
            "_id": 0,
            "IDCC": 478,
            "CPNEname": "CNPE des sociétés financières",
            "CPNEcode": 2
        },
        {
            "_id": 1,
            "IDCC": 1801,
            "CPNEname": "CNPEFP des sociétés d’assistance",
            "CPNEcode": 4
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried changing the filenames and changing the const routes in app.js